# Automapper many to many map fields from join

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I am using Asp.net core, EF Core and Automapper.  I have a many to many (kind of, in EF Core its necessary to use a join table for this) and am having trouble mapping an additional field in the join table to the related collection inside the DTO I am returning.

These are my entities (abbreviated):

Event entity:

```
public class Event
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public ICollection<EventAttendee> Attendees { get; set; }
}
```

AppUser entity:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EventAttendee> AttendingEvents { get; set; }
}
```

EventAttendee entity:

```
public class EventAttendee
{
    public int AppUserId { get; set; }
    public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public Event Event { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateJoined { get; set; }
}
```

EventToReturnDto:

```
public class EventToReturnDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AttendeeDto> Attendees { get; set; }
}
```

AttendeeDto:

```
public class AttendeeDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateJoined { get; set; }
}
```

Automapper profile:

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<AppUser, AttendeeDto>();
        CreateMap<EventAttendee, AttendeeDto>();
        CreateMap<Event, EventToReturnDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Attendees,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Attendees.Select(y => y.AppUser).ToList()));
    }    
}
```

Query:

```
var events = await _context.Events
    .Include(a => a.Attendees).ThenInclude(x => x.AppUser)
    .OrderBy(e => e.Date)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

var eventsToReturn = _mapper.Map<List<EventToReturnDto>>(events);
```

This results in the following output (I at least get the user information) but I can't figure out how to get the 'DateJoined' property from the EventAttendee into the collection of Attendees returned and just get the default date as follows:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Event 2",
    "attendees": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "userName": "Dave",
            "dateJoined": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "userName": "Jane",
            "dateJoined": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
        }
    ]
},
```

How would I go about creating the mapping to output the DateJoined property?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you don’t need both of these lines:

```
CreateMap<AppUser, AttendeeDto>();
CreateMap<EventAttendee, AttendeeDto>();
```

Because of your mapping instructions for the event, you are actually just mapping the `AppUser` but skip the `EventAttendee` completely. That is also why you are not able to get the `DateJoined` property.

Instead, you should map the event just to the event DTO and then make a custom mapping for the `EventAttendee`:

```
CreateMap<EventAttendee, AttendeeDto>()
   .ForMember(d => d.Id, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.AppUserId))
   .ForMember(d => d.UserName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.AppUser.UserName))
   .ForMember(d => d.DateJoined, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.DateJoined));
CreateMap<Event, EventToReturnDto>();
```

So now, inside the event mapping, you are mapping the `EventAttendee` collection to an `AttendeeDto` collection, so you just need to set up the mapping for that. And within that, you can simply use navigation properties to access related entities.